# Train Data & Test Data in Data science

Tags: data-science

I am relatively new Data science in python and was exploring some competition on data science, i am getting confused with "Training data Set" and "Test Data Set" . Some projects have merged both and some they have kept separate.  What is the rationale behind having two data sets. Any advise will be helpful thanks

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set

Answer (score 3):

"Training data" and "testing data" refer to subsets of the data you wish to analyze. If a supervised machine learning algorithm is being used to do something to your data (ex. to classify data points into clusters), the algorithm needs to be "trained".

Some examples of supervised machine learning algorithms are Support Vector Machines (SVM) and Linear Regression. They can be used to classify or cluster data that has many dimensions, allowing us to clump data points that are similar together.

These algorithms need to be trained with a subset of the data (the "training set") being analyzed before they are used on the "test set". Essentially, the training provides an algorithm an opportunity to infer a general solution for some new data it gets presented, much in the same way we as humans train so we can handle new situations in the future.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really great explanation, last one question, why in some model people merger training and test data and in some they are kept separate. Appreciate your help.

Comment: To my knowledge, your testing and training data should always be kept separate. The reason being that when you train your algorithm, it should be kept ignorant of data that's supposed to be "unknown". If the training set contains elements from the testing set, it's contaminated.

Answer (score 0):

A Dataset is a list of rows and can be split into training and test segments. The reason this is done is to keep a CLEAR separation between the rows of data that are used during the training process of the code (think of it like flashcards that you use to "train" a baby to learn objects) and the rows of data that are used (when you are testing the baby to learn objects). You want them to be separate in order to get an accurate score for how well the algorithm performed (e.g. the baby got 9/10 correct when tested). If you mixed the training rows and the testinrows you won't know if the baby just memorized the training results or actually knew how to recognize 9/10 new images.

Generally, datasets are given as one set because during code execution it is good to randomly select training and test sets by selecting rows randomly. That way you can run the training a few times and the test various times and can take the average. For example, the baby might get 9/10 the first time,6/10 the next, and 7/10 the last. The average accuracy would then be 73.3%. This is a better representation than just trying it once (which as you can see is not completely accurate).

Answer (score 0):

Train data set is for the training of your model and after it got trained how will it be checked that how much accurate the trained model is? For that, we use test data set and we usually split the available data into two pieces 1 for training and 1 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

`Case 1` - `when train and test datasets are merged into one` - It is advised to split the whole data into train, cross-validation and test sets with ratio 60:20:20 (train:CV:test). The idea is to use train data to build the model and use CV data to test the validity of the model and parameters. Your model should never see the test data until final prediction stage. So basically, you should be using train and CV data to build the model and making it robust.

`Case 2` - `when train and test datasets are separate` - You should split train data into train and CV data sets. Alternatively, you could perform k-fold cross-validation on train set.

In most cases, the split is done randomly. However, in cases when the data is time-dependent, then the split cannot be random.

Answer (score 0):

The training set is used to build the model. This contains a set of data that has target and predictor variables. This is the data which model has already seen while training and so (after finding optimum parameters), gives good accuracy (or other model performance parameter).

Test set is used to evaluate how well the model does with data outside the training set(which model has not seen). Already developed model(during training) is used for prediction and the results are compared against the preclassifed data. The model is adjusted to minimize error on the test set.